# Modifier letter capital H with the font Linux Libertine

Tags: fonts, unicode, libertine

I would like to be able to use the modifier letter capital H (Unicode code : U+ 1D34) in my thesis whose font is Linux Libertine. But it does not display well. I would like to have some help with that if possible (changing the font would be my very last option). Thanks beforehand.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine}

\begin{document}


pjèlè\char"1D34

\end{document}
```

Comment: Quite curiously Libertinus Serif (that is arguably better than Linux Libertine) hasn't the glyph, but Libertinus Sans does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the otf fonts found in the
[Libertine](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/libertine) package I
get a tofu (as in no character is displayed at all, just a
box):

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{LinLibertine_R.otf}

\begin{document}
pjèlèᴴ
\end{document}
```

[image: 1]

which means that font doesn't have the concerned character.
In this case, I am afraid, there is no other alternative but
to change the font, but the good news is there is a way to
change the font of just one particular character like this:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{LinLibertine_R.otf}
\newfontfamily\noto{NotoSerif}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{ᴴ}{{\noto ᴴ}}

\begin{document}
pjèlèᴴ
\end{document}
```

[image: 2]

Comment: Thanks for this solution. I think that that should help me. Does it mean that if I want to have another character that does not display, I should change the font of that character too the way you did it (in plus of the others)?

Comment: When I also compile your code, there is an error : ! Undefined control sequence.
ᴴ->{\noto
ᴴ}
l.9 pjèlèᴴ
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
Missing character: There is no ᴴ in font [LinLibertine_R.otf]/OT:script=latn;la
nguage=dflt;mapping=tex-text;!
[1

Comment: You must add \usepackage{noto} and change \noto to \notoserif

Comment: Thanks. But it also changes all the font too. The font became more bold.

Comment: Place \usepackage{noto} before \setmainfont{...}.

Comment: I am extremely sorry, I forgot to add an important command in the answer, because of which you got the error. Please try the updated code.

Comment: I am glad that this is working for you. Unfortunately you will have to add such commands manually for all such characters. Also I don't think it is advisable. Please use a font which has all the characters. Mixing font-shapes is considered a bad practice.

Comment: It works perfectly now. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

### The Most Important Thing.  I Mean It.

The first thing you should *always* do when you get a missing character error is to set `\tracinglostchars=3`.  Because of a bit of technical debt to the 1980s, the default behavior of TeX, when you request a character that the current font does not have, is to *silently* fail and print an error message somewhere in the middle of the `.log` file.  `\trachinglostchars=3` overrides this and makes the error an error.

In fact, there’s no good reason not to add this to all your documents.  If the maintainers felt they could break backwards compatibility with some old document that only compiles because of this ever so useful and important documented feature, `\tracinglostchars=3` or perhaps `tracinglostchars=2`, which would still compile it just as well and at least *notify* you there’s a problem, might even be the default.

Without that, you will need to go over every draft of your document with an eagle eye, hoping that you don’t overlook any missing characters.  Tedious, repetitive, error-prone, mechanical drudgery that takes humans a long time to get mostly right is what computers were invented for.  But you have to tell them *exactly* what you need them to do, or they won’t.

But most TeXnicians don’t know about it and none of the tutorials that a search engine sends them to will tell them.

If you remember nothing else from this answer, remember that.

### The Solution

In this case, however, that only tells you what you already knew: that Linux Libertine does not have this character.

The first thing to try if you need a version of Libertine with more glyphs is Khaled Hosny’s extension of the Libertine/Biolinum family, the Libertinus fonts.   They don’t happen to cover this particular one either, though.

So, the best approach is to use a scaled superscript capital H.  This needs to be from the same font family amd scaled to a relative size (from `relsize`) so it will work in, for example, a larger, bold, sans-serif header.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{scrarticle}
\tracinglostchars=3
\usepackage{libertinus}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\newcommand\supH{\textsuperscript{\textsmaller[2]{H}}}
\newunicodechar{^^^^1d34}{\supH} % ᴴ

\begin{document}

\section*{Pjèlèᴴ}
pjèlèᴴ

\end{document}
```

[image: Libertinus sample]

I also defined the alias `\supH`, which you can type instead of `\char"1D34` if you need an ASCII command.  You may change this to whatever you prefer.  I then set the Unicode character active and had it call this command.

Comment: Thanks for your useful answer and also about how to trace a missing character. That is very useful. Thanks